# Can I suppress Send SMS option when calling ACTION_DIAL intent

Tags: android, android-intent

My team is developing an Android app that includes the ability to call and talk to customer support. We are calling an Intent with ACTION_DIAL, which brings up the dialer with the phone number pre-populated, as expected. In the device emulator, we also see links to Create a new Contact and Add to a Contact, which are fine, but we want to suppress the Send SMS link, since there is no way for us to read messages sent to that number. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass a parameter or change a setting that disables SMS messaging for that one invocation, but I'm open to other solutions. Searches that I've done haven't turned up anything.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

No.  There's no way of knowing what dialer is being launched for action dial-  OEMs all have the option of using their own, or the user can even download one of their own.  There's no way of knowing what options those dialers support, and definitely no way of configuring them.  Even if there was, a dialer app could ignore the configuration.  You may want to use ACTION_CALL instead, which requires additional permissions but will directly call without bringing up a prefilled dialer.